# Extracting and Processing GPUTemperature Information Using Regexp

Tags: regex, bash, ubuntu

I need to extract and process graphic card temperature integer the following output from Linux Ubuntu application, sensors:

```
amdgpu-pci-0c00
Adapter: PCI adapter
fan1:        1972 RPM
temp1:        +50.0°C  (crit =  +0.0°C, hyst =  +0.0°C)

amdgpu-pci-0600
Adapter: PCI adapter
fan1:        1960 RPM
temp1:        +47.0°C  (crit =  +0.0°C, hyst =  +0.0°C)

amdgpu-pci-0200
Adapter: PCI adapter
fan1:        1967 RPM
temp1:        +52.0°C  (crit =  +0.0°C, hyst =  +0.0°C)

pch_skylake-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +33.0°C

amdgpu-pci-0900
Adapter: PCI adapter
fan1:        1893 RPM
temp1:        +51.0°C  (crit =  +0.0°C, hyst =  +0.0°C)

amdgpu-pci-0300
Adapter: PCI adapter
fan1:        1992 RPM
temp1:        +53.0°C  (crit =  +0.0°C, hyst =  +0.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +24.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +23.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +21.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
```

Suppose I want to extract information that associates with amd gpu temperature, which are 50, 47, 52, 51, and 53. So far what I have is executing the following code:

```
sensors|grep temp| grep -Eo '\+[0-9]{0,9}'
```

and I got:

```
+50
+0
+0
+47
+0
+0
+52
+0
+0
+32
+51
+0
+0
+53
+0
+0
```

So I need to figure it out:

1. The regexp look-around  assertion so that it captures integers that has + sign in the beginning of the number, without displaying the + (plus) sign.
2. A way to grab only amdgpu information, so that it won't grab other info.
3. A way to process those temperature numbers, for example I could write a bash script to process the numbers whereas if the temperature is less than 30, do this, if more than 70, do that. Should I put the result in an array and do a loop, or is there any other practical way?

Please help. 
regards

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: the script will go through all those gpu temperatures, when one of the numbers is less than 30, it will say, "temp is less than 30". When it is more than 70, it will say, "temp is more than 70".

Comment: You asked a question and accepted the first answer you got within about 1 hour. What are the odds that that was the best answer? And yet by accepting it you ensured that almost no-one else would read your question or provide alternative answers. That's too bad.

Comment: ok, I usually select the first correct answer as the best answer without wait for different answers submitted. I keep your comment in mind, and will wait for different answers before check for the best answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you have desired temperatures stored in an array, you can then do the math with them.

`arr=( $( IFS=$'\n' gawk 'BEGIN{ RS="\n\n"} { if($0 ~ /amdgpu/) print $0 }' test.txt | gawk 'BEGIN{ FS="[+.]" } { if($1 ~ /temp1:/) print $2 }' ) )
echo "${arr[*]}"
50 47 52 51 53`

test.txt contains your sample output. Getting input from sensors command (not tested)

`arr=( $( sensors | IFS=$'\n' gawk 'BEGIN{ RS="\n\n"} { if($0 ~ /amdgpu/) print $0 }' | gawk 'BEGIN{ FS="[+.]" } { if($1 ~ /temp1:/) print $2 }' ) )
echo "${arr[*]}"
50 47 52 51 53`

Comment: is it possible instead of using test.text, use 'sensors' command?

Comment: Added that option to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can also get the temps with a single grep, if you're willing to use Perl-like regexp:

```
sensors | grep -oP 'temp\d:\s+\+\K\d+'
```

Where we grep for `temp` followed by a digit and a colon, then a at least one whitespace character and a plus-sign, after that we give the lookbehind assertion `\K` which discards everything before it, and the final capture is just `\d+` (one or more digits).

Comment: how to put those into array in bash?

Comment: If the output doesn't have spaces (like this one doesn't), you can just use normal process substitution within parentheses like so: `temps_array=($(sensors | grep -oP 'temp\d:\s+\+\K\d+'))`

Comment: ok, how do you extract only amdgpu temp, leaving skylake processor temp?

Comment: Add a `grep´ with the `-A` or `after` argument in front of the first one like so: `sensors | grep amdgpu -A 3 | grep -oP 'temp\d:\s+\+\K\d+'`