# Extracting Ubuntu Sensors Command Using Scripts

Tags: regex, bash, ubuntu, awk

this question is the continuation of [Extracting and Processing GPUTemperature Information Using Regexp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49985716/extracting-and-processing-gputemperature-information-using-regexp)

Basically I want to extract GPUs temperatures information using sensors command and scripts like gawk and bash.

Example of sensors output will be like this:

```
amdgpu-pci-0c00
Adapter: PCI adapter
fan1:        1972 RPM
temp1:        +50.0°C  (crit =  +0.0°C, hyst =  +0.0°C)

amdgpu-pci-0600
Adapter: PCI adapter
fan1:        1960 RPM
temp1:        +47.0°C  (crit =  +0.0°C, hyst =  +0.0°C)

amdgpu-pci-0200
Adapter: PCI adapter
fan1:        1967 RPM
temp1:        +52.0°C  (crit =  +0.0°C, hyst =  +0.0°C)

pch_skylake-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +33.0°C

amdgpu-pci-0900
Adapter: PCI adapter
fan1:        1893 RPM
temp1:        +51.0°C  (crit =  +0.0°C, hyst =  +0.0°C)

amdgpu-pci-0300
Adapter: PCI adapter
fan1:        1992 RPM
temp1:        +53.0°C  (crit =  +0.0°C, hyst =  +0.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +24.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +23.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +21.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
```

I want to print each GPU with its label and temperature, based on the ascending order of bus ID. For example, based on the previous output, the first GPU, GPU0, will be the one with label amdgpu-pci-0200, GPU1 will be amdgpu-pci-0300, until the last one GPU4 is amdgpu-pci-0c00. This is excluding coretemp-isa-0000, since it's not a GPU. Regardless the fact that the bus ID is consecutive or skipping, I want to label it in order at ascending manner.

The following bash code will extract all the GPU temps without doing the sorting properly.

```
#!/bin/bash

while [ 1 ]
do
        temp=( $( sensors | IFS=$'\n' gawk 'BEGIN{ RS="\n\n"} { if($0 ~ /amdgpu/) print $0 }' | gawk 'BEGIN{ FS="[+.]" } { if($1 ~ /temp1:/) print $2 }' ))   
        let j=0
        for i in "${temp[@]}"
        do
                echo -en  "GPU $j temp is $i \r "
                j=$(($j +1))
                sleep 1
        done
done
```

How do I sort it out?

regards

Comment: Assuming that `Example of sensors output will be like this:`is the input to a tool you're asking for help with please provide the **exact** expected output from the script you're trying to write. Explain how we can know that `coretemp-isa-0000` is not a GPU and why there's a `sleep 1` in your shell script and why it's placed inside the loop on array contents output by `sensors` rather than the surrounding infinite loop.

Comment: the GPU temp is the one with GPU text and coretemp-isa-0000 doesn't have it. Obviously you figured it out in your edited answer. The script runs infinitely keep telling about the temperature, that is why it need 1 second delay for the operator to read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't provide the actual expected output or provide some of the details on how to parse the input so this is a bit of a guess but it may be what you're looking for:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/bin/env bash

#while :
#do
    cat file |
    gawk '
        BEGIN { RS="" }
        $1 ~ /amdgpu/ {
            temp = "N/A"
            for (i=1; i<NF; i++) {
                if ($i == "temp1:") {
                    temp = gensub(/^[^0-9]*([0-9]+).*/,"\\1",1,$(i+1))
                }
            }
            temps[$1] = temp
        }
        END {
            PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"
            for (id in temps) {
                print "GPU" (++cnt), id, temps[id]
            }
        }
    '
    #sleep 1
#done

$ ./tst.sh
GPU1 amdgpu-pci-0200 52
GPU2 amdgpu-pci-0300 53
GPU3 amdgpu-pci-0600 47
GPU4 amdgpu-pci-0900 51
GPU5 amdgpu-pci-0c00 50
```

Just change `cat file` to `sensors` and uncomment the lines to activate the infinite loop (assuming you have a reason for doing that) when you're happy with that.

The above uses GNU awk for gensub() and sorted_in.

Comment: this is great, however I need to use sorted temps array so that I can manipulate it using bash script. So that the array would be like: temps[0]= 52, temps[1]=53, ..., temps[4]= 50. Sorry I wasn't being clear

Comment: Ask a new question and this time be clear. Even with your comment I still don't know what it is you actually want output.

Comment: ok, I just created a new question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52625383/extracting-sensors-output-into-sorted-array)