# Extracting Sensors Output into Sorted Array

Tags: bash, ubuntu, awk

this question is the continuation of [Extracting Ubuntu Sensors Command Using Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52606325/extracting-ubuntu-sensors-command-using-scripts)

Since the question was poorly written, I'm rewording the question in form of new question.

Basically I want to extract GPUs temperatures information using sensors command and scripts like gawk and bash.

Example of sensors output will be like this:

```
amdgpu-pci-0c00
Adapter: PCI adapter
fan1:        1972 RPM
temp1:        +50.0°C  (crit =  +0.0°C, hyst =  +0.0°C)

amdgpu-pci-0600
Adapter: PCI adapter
fan1:        1960 RPM
temp1:        +47.0°C  (crit =  +0.0°C, hyst =  +0.0°C)

amdgpu-pci-0200
Adapter: PCI adapter
fan1:        1967 RPM
temp1:        +52.0°C  (crit =  +0.0°C, hyst =  +0.0°C)

pch_skylake-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +33.0°C

amdgpu-pci-0900
Adapter: PCI adapter
fan1:        1893 RPM
temp1:        +51.0°C  (crit =  +0.0°C, hyst =  +0.0°C)

amdgpu-pci-0300
Adapter: PCI adapter
fan1:        1992 RPM
temp1:        +53.0°C  (crit =  +0.0°C, hyst =  +0.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +24.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +23.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +21.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
```

The GPU temp information is labeled amdgpu-pci-"BUS_ID", so we don't care about other label scheme (skylake-virtual nor coretemp-isa). Things need to be done are:

1. Extracting the GPU temperatures info, for example amdgpu-pci-0c00
   has 50 degree, and put in into an array.
2. The array index should be started with 0 and ascending in the order
   of BUS ID.

If using the above data, the array assuming a is the name, would be:

```
a[0] = 52 ;amdgpu-pci-0200
a[1] = 53 ;amdgpu-pci-0300
a[2] = 47 ;amdgpu-pci-0600
a[3] = 51 ;amdgpu-pci-0900
a[4] = 50 ;amdgpu-pci-0c00
```

What I need for the output is an infinite loop that keep updating the array index with its value:

```
0 => 52
1 => 53
2 => 47
3 => 51
4 => 57
```

The new value should print over the old value so it won't trail. The update should have 1 second delay so the operator can easily evaluate the values.

The extracting and sorting could be done by GAwk, but I need it to be stored in an array in bash so that I can use it for other process.

regards

Comment: Unfortunately your question only contains requirements: it is not showing any efforts from your side to solve this problem yourself.  Please [edit] your question to show [your attempt far](http://whathaveyoutried.com), and you'll be much more likely to receive answers that help you progress.  Show us your work so far as a [mcve], the result you were expecting and the results you got, and we'll help you figure it out. It may help to re-read [ask].

Comment: @tobby-speight, this question actually the 3rd part of 1 big question. My effort so far was in the link of the first paragraph. regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reusing parts from your script and Ed Mortons answer I think this might work for you:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true
do
  while read -r i temp ; do
    echo -en  "GPU $i temp is $temp \r "
    sleep 1
  done < <(
    sensors | gawk '
      !NF {name=""}
      /amdgpu/ {
        name=$1
      }
      /^temp1:/ && name {
        temps[name]=gensub(/^[^0-9]*([0-9]+).*/,"\\1",1,$2);
      }
      END {
        PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"
        ctr=0;
        for (i in temps) {
          print ctr++,temps[i]
        }
      } '
  )
done
```

Edit: if you need to store the values to an array (as stated in the question) for other purposes you can do it like this:

```
temps=( $( sensors | gawk '...' ) )
```

In this case change the print command in awk to only print temps[i]. My approach can be easily extended to include other values from the sensors output (like the gpu labels or fan speed).

Comment: this is perfect. I appreciate your help.